# What's the difference between 在 and 于 as a preposition?

Tags: word-choice

When I was writing a simple paragraph about 自我介绍, I wanted to say that "I was born in XXX."

I wasn't sure about how to say it and then looked for some examples of how to say it in Chinese and came across two characters :

"在" and "于"
(I just knew about 于, I had never paid attention to this character before).

Both can mean "in, on, at" and can be used as a preposition to indicate a location as well.

Now, what's the difference between two characters?

Will there be any difference if I say :

> 我出生在XXX。

and

> 我出生于XXX。

???

Thank you!

Comment: The tag `simplified-chinese` is specifically for discussing Simplified Chinese characters - please don’t assign it to questions not to do with characters.

Comment: 于 always more literary than 在

Answer (score 4, accepted):

王得屹's answer is basically correct, **在** is used in **colloquial** sentences more and **于** is used in **literary** sentences more.

I would provide examples to illustrate the point more clearly:

"生(于)中国" = "出生(在)中国" (*we don't say 生在中国 because 生 is more literary, 在 is more colloquial, mixing the two make it sound unnatural*)

"逝(于)日本" = "(在)日本逝世" (*we don't say 逝在日本 because 逝 is more literary, 在 is more colloquial, mixing the two make it sound unnatural; meanwhile, 死 and 在 in 死在日本 are both colloquial terms*)

"生于中国" and "逝于日本" are more literary

"出生在中国" and "在日本逝世" / 死在日本 are more colloquial

*unlike 逝, 逝世 is more suitable for colloquial sentences*

Answer (score 2):

Both 我出生在XXX。and 我出生于XXX。are right. They have the same meaning.
In my experience with the two words '在' and '于' as a Chinese speaker, they all adpositions which have similar use. Both of them can be used to indicate time and location.
The only different I think between them is '在' is often used in spoken language but '于' is often used in formal occasions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111222/discussion-on-answer-by-masterbee-whats-the-difference-between--and--as-a-pre).